# How to load the 'stringr' package in R?

Tags: r, package

I am using the "Mining Twitter for Airline Sentiment" tutorial to learn R. (tutorial at http://www.inside-r.org/howto/mining-twitter-airline-consumer-sentiment.)

The parsing algorithm requires loading the external "stringr" library. The R gui terminal consistently says it cannot find the library, even though multiple references exist online.

This is my first experience with an R tutorial. Any suggestions?

Thanks,
@brianpiercy

Comment: To learn R you should start with "introduction to R". You need to learn to walk before running.

Answer (score 27):

```
install.packages("stringr", repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
library("stringr")
```

Comment: Thanks @GSee, but no luck. "Warning message: ... ... package 'stringr' is not available"

Comment: Then you need to tell us what version of R you're running. What are the results of `sessionInfo()` ? (Although this is a little surprising -- usually this happens with more recent packages, `stringr` is not that new ...)

Comment: @bjpcjp: Do you get the same error message when you try to download other packages?

Comment: R version 2.12.1, on Ubuntu 11.4 (dual-boot setup on HP laptop). Other packages (admittedly only 2-3 thus far) loaded w/o problems. FWIW, I'm following both Intro to R and OReilly's R Cookbook.

Comment: @bjpcjp Maybe not the answer you're looking for, but you could install a newer version of R. My answer works for me on Ubuntu 64 bit with R 2.14.1

Comment: Maybe a bit late, but I would like to give my contribution to the thread. GSee's answer worked like a charm with R 3.2.2 (Windows). It should be noted that stringr requires the following libraries: stringi and magrittr as clearly mentioned here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html

Answer (score 4):

DWin was right, learn more about "R Package" [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Packages).

You may try [CloudStat: Twitter analysis](http://cloudst.at/index.php?do=/kafechew/blog/twitter-analysis/).

Summary for newbie:

Go to [stringr | Cran-R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html) download the source file. Through your R Gui:

> Packages > Install Package(s) from local zip file

Then, Load the library

> library(stringr)

Hope it help.